# Where does python open files to on a mac?

Tags: python, file, text, file-io, filesystems

I made a simple python script which creates a text file. The contents of the script are

```
f = open("New", "w")
f.close
```

Now I moved the script to the desktop (I'm on a mac) and ran it, and nothing shows up. No file is created on the desktop that is visible for me.

I actually made this little script because one of my other scripts involves opening/creating a text file and reading from it. I entered the information wrong while in my program forever, and now the entire thing is broken and I cant fix it because I have no idea where it's created the darn text file. I was under the impression that just opening a file with giving it an absolute path would create it in the same directory as the script. I seem to have been mistaken.

I've been launching the script from the terminal with the command

```
python3 /Users/me/Desktop/script.py
```

Because of that, I feel like its creating the file somewhere in the python3 install location or within wherever the python3 unix exec is located. I think. Can't check.

Are any of you guys willing to help out?

-pipsqueaker117

EDIT: [Here's a link](http://pastebin.com/ywm3YpkV) to the big program which broke.

Comment: Do you know what is meant by the 'working directory'? In the terminal immediately before you run your command, try the command `pwd` 'print working directory'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your file will be created in the current directory (most probably in `/Users/me/` if you just opened the terminal)

Try:

```
cd /Users/me/Desktop/
python3 /Users/me/Desktop/script.py
```

Comment: This solved the problem (and I'll mark it as such once it lets me). However, I'd still like to know where it was creating the files earlier

Comment: @pipsqueaker117 Thanks. It was creating the file in the current directory. If you are in the terminal and want to know what is the current directory do: `pwd`

Comment: Also, the code provided by drewk (+1) will output the current directory from your python script. The command `pwd` is to be entered in the terminal. Normally, both should be the same if your script does not change the current directory.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the tip. On a slightly unrelated note, do you happen to know how I would get the path of the python script  (from within the code itself find the folder it's contained in, I mean) so I can edit the code to avoid mishaps like this?

Comment: @pipsqueaker117 Yes. To know the path of your current script use: `os.path.realpath(__file__)`. It will give you the path of the current file (resolving any symlinks). To change the path use `os.chdir(…)`. You can also get the current path (the one in which files will be created by default) using: `os.getcwd()`.

Answer (score 8):

It'll be created in the current working directory, which is the directory from which you called the script.

Comment: @pipsqueaker117: Not even at the root of your home directory? How are you calling the script?

Comment: Actually, I just found them. They seem to have been placed within the /Users/me/ directory for some reason. Can you explain why?

Comment: @pipsqueaker117 because when you open a terminal, the current directory is set to `/Users/me`. That's why I wrote `most probably…` in my answer. I had the same issue once ;)

Comment: @pipsqueaker117 A program that is started inherits the current working directory from its parent.

Answer (score 2):

You can always ask:

```
import os 

cwd=os.getcwd()
print(cwd)
```

That will print the directory the file (without a path) will be opened in.

You can change to a specific directory (in Python) this way:

```
import os 

try:
    os.chdir('/Users/me/Desktop')
except OSError as e:
    print e
```

Answer (score 2):

You should modify your program to change the working directory (before you write the file) to the place where you want files to show up.

```
import os
os.chdir('/Users/me/Desktop') # or whatever
```

This should be a directory where you have permission to write files.